# iOS keyboard mapping for testing multiple keyboard layouts

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I am trying to write a automation script to test for keyboard mapping for multiple keyboard layouts on my ipad/iphone app.

type all the characters from current keyboard layout (ex English keyboard layout) , next change the keyboard layout to French and type all the keys on the keyboard layout.

i tired to use myapp.keys["a"].tap() and it types character "a" on my app
next if i try same myapp.keys["a"].tap() on a French keyboard layout again character "a" is typed on my app.
But this does not help me in testing for any keyboard mapping issues coz myapp.keys["a"] searches for "a" anywhere in the keyboard and types it.

Instead i want to test if the character "a" exists on the first row for French keyboard and on English keyboard character "q" exists.

Comment: how you are changing keyboard? is these custom keyboards or device keyboards?

Comment: its device keyboards, and was planning on tapping the globe icon on the keyboard to switch between the various keyboard layouts i have added.